# Spark JVM RSS Memory (Executor Physical Memory Usage)

Tags: apache-spark, memory, jvm, heap-memory, amazon-emr

When enabling process tree metrics for Spark, I can get the ProcessTreeJVMRSSMemory metric from the application logs. Per [Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/monitoring.html) the jvm rss memory is: “Resident Set Size: number of pages the process has in real memory”).

If for example, `"ProcessTreeJVMRSSMemory":934203392`, how can you extrapolate physical memory/heap used from the number of pages in ram?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. RSS is exactly the amount of physical memory used by a process.

Comment: Ah, I see. The documentation is misleading. It should be not the *number of pages*, but the *total size of pages*.

Comment: oh okay. that makes sense. Is it accurate to say that this rss value is the amount of memory used by a particular task (independent of other tasks) over the task lifetime? Interested in this because I'm wanting to determine max physical memory used by an executor.